# Installing jvisualvm on CentOS

Tags: centos, java, jvisualvm

I installed Java on my CentOS machine, but I don't have jvisualvm:

```
[root@ bin]# ls -la /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/
total 496
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 2012-05-22 17:31 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root  4096 2012-02-15 03:11 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 41120 2012-02-15 03:13 java
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 41088 2012-02-15 03:13 keytool
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 41168 2012-02-15 03:13 orbd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 41128 2012-02-15 03:13 pack200
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 42368 2012-02-15 03:13 policytool
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 41080 2012-02-15 03:13 rmid
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 41088 2012-02-15 03:13 rmiregistry
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 41088 2012-02-15 03:13 servertool
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 41176 2012-02-15 03:13 tnameserv
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 91352 2012-02-15 03:13 unpack200
```

How do I install it?

Comment: I think you have to install the Sun JDK, not Open JDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Oracle's web site:

> Various optional tools, including Java VisualVM, are provided with
>   Sun's distribution of the Java Development Kit (JDK)

Did you install the Java JDK (Java Development Kit) or just the runtime (JRE)?

The Java 6 JDK is available for download at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6-downloads-1637591.html

The Java 7 JDK is available at:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1637583.html

Or are you limited to only using OpenJDK?  In which case you can download VisualVM from http://visualvm.java.net/download.html